# 504 in a request to Typeform API using request library

Tags: python, request, timeout

I am integrating the answers given by some users to a typeform poll. I am using the request library and 50% of the times I get the response and 50% of the times i get a 504 code. Does anyone have an advice/link on how to solve this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It would help us if you show your code and how you're integrating the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This may not be something that you can correct on on the client side.

A 504 status code indicates that some gateway server or service attempted to forward your request to the origin server and either received a 504 from upstream or no response within it's timeout interval.  For example, this is a code that is used by Amazon's [CDN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-504-gateway-timeout.html) and [load-balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504) services.  If the failure ratio is close to 50% with a significant sample size, there's a good chance there's load-balancing involved.

As with any 5xx status code, the implication is that once the issue causing the failure is resolved upstream, you should be able to send the same request without modification and get a successful response.  So any attempt to mitigate it on your side should be made with respect to retry/backoff strategy, rather than changing the content of your request.